# How to start Word for repeated UI tests?

Tags: c#, testing, ms-word, coded-ui-tests

I'm on a testing team and we are writing tests for a Word Plugin.  We have a start word method that we reun before each of your tests.  It works fine for the individual tests but when we put them in an ordered test, it throws an exception.  This is what we had before:

```
if (!Playback.IsInitialized)
{
     Playback.Initialize();
}

// Launch '%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE'
ApplicationUnderTest wINWORDApplication = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(exePath, altPath);

if (killAllPreviousWordProcesses == true)
{
       wINWORDApplication.Maximized = true;
}
```

After looking around we foudn a post that suggested using Process.Start() instead of ApplicationUnderTest.  This was the code they suggested.

```
Process np = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe");
while (np.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  }

 //This line throws the error
 WinWindow npWindow = UITestControlFactory.FromWindowHandle(np.MainWindowHandle) as WinWindow;

 MessageBox.Show(npWindow.Name);
 ApplicationUnderTest aut = ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess(np);
 MessageBox.Show(aut.Title);
```

We changed it to use Word (replacing the string with "WINWORD", we've also tried the path) but now we get a NullReferenceException everytime we run the method.  I've checked everything for null and made sure the np.MainWindowHandle was not zero but its still giving me the error.  Any ideas to fix this or alternative suggestions?

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindFromWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(IntPtr windowHandle)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FromWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControlFactory.FromWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle)
at Common.BaseUIMapClasses.BaseUIMap.startWord(Boolean killAllPreviousWordProcesses, Boolean maximizeWord, String exePath, String altPath) in C:\Source1\Common\BaseUIMap.cs:line 170
```

Comment: What throws the nullreference exception?  You might just paste the relevant exception lines.

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear.  When it blows up you receive a stack trace that describes exactly what the nullreference exception is.  Post that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/a194d03c-c6d2-4484-b536-4f751d013927/)

Comment: Wow! I swear this didn't come up on my google! Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Nikola. I see problem is solved, but I want to share my interesting case. Let's imagine I have one test class and it's base class. Base class defines some `ClassInitialize` actions. Test class has `CodedUITest` attribute, but base class also has attribute - `[TestClass]`. This broke everything.

```
[CodedUITest]
public class ProjectTabTests : CodedUIFunctionalTestBase
{ 
    [TestInitialize]
    public override void SetUp()
    {
        base.SetUp();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
    }
}

[TestClass] // this broke everything! remove it!
public class CodedUIFunctionalTestBase
{
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        KillProcess(Constanst.ProcessName);

        Playback.PlaybackSettings.SmartMatchOptions = SmartMatchOptions.None;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot; // here I got internal NullReferenceException
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 10000;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 10000;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.ThinkTimeMultiplier = 1;
        Playback.PlaybackSettings.MaximumRetryCount = 3;

        Application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(Constants.Application);
    }
}
```

Hope this post could help somebody.